# PHP - How to merge foreach arrays into one loop

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my code:

```
$url = "https://www.leaseweb.com/dedicated-servers/single-processor";

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$n = $xpath->query('//td[@data-column-name="Model"]');
$r = $xpath->query('//td[@data-column-name="RAM"]');

foreach ($n as $entry) {
    $Name = $entry->nodeValue;
    $RAM  = $r->nodeValue;
    echo " $Name - RAM: $RAM<br>";
}
```

I successfully echo `$Name` but i can not get the value for `$RAM` because i do not have it in my array. My question is how i can add `$r` into this foreach loop and make it work ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `foreach ($n as $key => $entry) {
    $Name = $entry->nodeValue;
    $RAM  = $r[$key]->nodeValue;
    echo " $Name - RAM: $RAM<br>";
}`

Comment: I don't get it. Can you make it as an answer ?

Comment: can you please tell me how data of `$r` is related to data of `$n` then i can help you.

Comment: Are you shure that $n->length == $r->length?

Comment: Yes that is for sure!

Comment: I have the same amount results for `$Name` as i have for `$RAM`!

Comment: can you post some sample of your $n and $r

Comment: The complete code is posted above in the edited question. You can now test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Documentation is kind of ambiguous at this point. `DOMXPath::query` returns a `DOMNodeList` which isn't really an `Iterator` nor does it seems to implement `ArrayAccess` but rather implements `Traversable` which doesn't have a particular signature that's helpful to traverse the object.

Here's something that comes to mind:

```
$item = 0;
foreach ($n as $entry) {
    $Name = $entry->nodeValue;
    $RAM  = $r->item($item)->nodeValue;
    echo " $Name - RAM: $RAM<br>";
    $item++;
}
```

Something else that might work:

```
$iterator = new IteratorIterator($r);
$iterator->rewind();
foreach ($n as $entry) {
    $Name = $entry->nodeValue;
    $node = $iterator->current();
    $RAM  = $node->nodeValue;
    $iterator->next();
    echo " $Name - RAM: $RAM<br>";
}
```

**IteratorIterator class**:

> This iterator wrapper allows the conversion of anything that is Traversable into an Iterator. It is important to understand that most classes that do not implement Iterators have reasons as most likely they do not allow the full Iterator feature set. If so, techniques should be provided to prevent misuse, otherwise expect exceptions or fatal errors.

Comment: This is the only one working answer so far! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

use $key variable inside loop

```
   foreach ($n as $key => $entry) {
        $Name = $entry->nodeValue;
        $RAM  = $r[$key]->nodeValue;
        echo " $Name - RAM: $RAM<br>";
    }
```

Comment: Your blank screen could be a result of an error. Please check the errorlog

Answer (score 0):

You could try with current and next array functions ([php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php))

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$n = $xpath->query('//td[@data-column-name="Model"]');
$r = $xpath->query('//td[@data-column-name="RAM"]');
//Reset pointer to first element and assign to currR
$currR = reset($r);

foreach ($n as $entry) {
    $Name = $entry->nodeValue;
    $RAM  = $currR->nodeValue;
    echo " $Name - RAM: $RAM<br>";
    //Move pointer to next element and assign this to currR
    $currR = next($r);
}
```

Comment: It is not working. The complete code is posted above in the edited question. You can now test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
foreach ($n as $entry) {
    $Name = $entry->nodeValue;
    $RAM  = $r[$i]->nodeValue;
    echo " $Name - RAM: $RAM<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: if you can post print_r($r) then i can do some help